# Search By week in python

Tags: python, search, pandas-groupby, week-number

Hi everyone I'm trying to build a function that looks into a CSV file and returns me the group of data in a particular week.

```
    def searchWeek(week_Number):
  #dataLakeWeek = dataLake.groupby(dataLake.Week)
  week = dataLake.loc[dataLake["Week"] == f"{week_Number}","Agent":"atingimento"]
  week.groupby(dataLake['Week'])
  print(week)
```

So the idea would be to return all the data within week one grouped by week but by agents also. So if Guto R. has more then one data entry the date would add

```
           day       Agent  Resolved  Meta  Week  Year
0 2021-01-04  Bárbara D.        95    52     1  2021
1 2021-01-04    Danielly        83    52     1  2021
2 2021-01-04     Guto R.       125    52     1  2021
3 2021-01-04  Helaine S.        19    52     1  2021
4 2021-01-04     João M.        94    52     1  2021
5 2021-01-04     Guto R.       125    52     1  2021
```

Result would be

```
           day       Agent  Resolved  Meta  Week  Year
10 2021-01-04     Guto R.       250    104    1  2021
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby_agg`:

```
out = df.groupby(['Week', 'Year', 'Agent'], as_index=False) \
        .agg({'day': 'first', 'Agent': 'first', 'Resolved': 'sum',
              'Meta': 'sum', 'Week': 'first', 'Year': 'first'})
print(out)

# Output
          day       Agent  Resolved  Meta  Week  Year
0  2021-01-04  Bárbara D.        95    52     1  2021
1  2021-01-04    Danielly        83    52     1  2021
2  2021-01-04     Guto R.       250   104     1  2021
3  2021-01-04  Helaine S.        19    52     1  2021
4  2021-01-04     João M.        94    52     1  2021
```